# "Access the Camera" Message Popup Once Users Launch the App

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

My iOS app has a function that would access the camera, so every time users access that function, the app would popup a message (see attached image), I think this is nice.

But recently I found that this prompt would popup once users launch the app, I don't like this, how can I change it back? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: share you block of code which you used to access the camera then i can suggest best solution. thanks

Comment: Sorry, can I delete the question now? I just found the camera is really required upon app launch, so that prompt is correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if are you creating object of `AVCaptureDeviceInput`?
As per [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/AVCaptureDevice/requestAccessForMediaType:completionHandler:) "The first time you create any AVCaptureDeviceInput objects for a media type that requires permission, the system automatically displays an alert to request recording permission."

If thats the case just create only when you are going to use.